# Wine doesn't run normally anymore. Need to run wineserver before every command now

Tags: wine, playonlinux, winetricks

After installing `playonlinux` to test one of its scripts, running `wine` on any Windows executable or even `winecfg` does nothing. Running `winetricks` outputs:

```
------------------------------------------------------
wine cmd.exe /c echo '%ProgramFiles%' returned empty string
------------------------------------------------------
```

Searching that output online led to solutions that say to not run Wine as root, or to change ownership of the Wineprefix folder to the current user. That didn't help because I don't run Wine as root anyway and the `~/.wine` folder and everything in it belongs to me.

I haven't even run any application yet with `playonlinux`, but uninstalling it and even reinstalling everything Wine-related doesn't fix the problem (I use the ubuntu-wine ppa).

However, after accidentally using tab complete on the wrong thing, I learned that running `wineserver` before anything Wine-related makes it run as it normally would.

What did `playonlinux` do on install that possibly caused Wine to not run normally?

**Edit (2015/08/02)**
It wasn't `playonlinux`. It was a kernel problem. I mistakenly assumed it was the former because it was the only Wine-related package I marked for installation at the same time that I also upgraded to the problematic kernel version. See link in answer below for more details.

Comment: I have the same error but I hadn't installed `playonlinux`. Running `wineserver` before `wine` command really helps. What also helps is using `wine64` instead of `wine`. And it also appeared just yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be [error in Ubuntu kernel](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38982). There is fix already available - just upgrade to newer kernel version (3.13.0-61).

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```